# Inheriting / Nesting Traits on other Traits

Tags: rust

In Rust, is it possible to generalize a trait to always implement another trait, or to have a struct "inherit" its traits' implementations of other traits?

For instance, in the following code, I don't want to have to implement equality between every possible type of `Length`. If I implement it on the trait, how do I use it on the structs that implement that trait?

```rust
// `Length` Trait, which includes a standardized unit
trait Length {
  fn _standardized(&self) -> f64;
}
impl std::cmp::PartialEq for dyn Length {
  fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
    self._standardized() == other._standardized()
  }
}

// `Centimeters`
struct Centimeters(f64);
impl Length for Centimeters {
  fn _standardized(&self) -> f64 {
    let &Centimeters(cm) = self;
    cm
  }
}

// `Inches`
struct Inches(i32);
impl Length for Inches {
  fn _standardized(&self) -> f64 {
    let &Inches(inches) = self;
    inches as f64 * 2.54
  }
}

fn main() {
  let foot = Inches(12);
  let meter = Centimeters(100.0);

  let cmp = if foot == meter { "equal" } else { "not equal" };
  println!("One foot is {} to one meter.", cmp);
}
```

Currently, that throws an error:

```
binary operation `==` cannot be applied to type `partial_ord::Centimeters`

note: an implementation of `std::cmp::PartialEq` might be missing for `partial_ord::Centimeters`
rustc(E0369)
```

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28135373/inheritance-of-generic-trait-implementation), I also tried:

```rust
impl<T> std::cmp::PartialEq for T where T: Length {
```

which gives
`` conflicting implementations of trait `std::cmp::PartialEq<&_>` for type `&_`: ``

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do? If so, what is it?
(And, if you're looking for extra kudos, what gap in my Rust paradigm does this example highlight?)

Comment: When [specialization](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/31844) comes around this is may be possible, but what you're currently trying to do isn't. You can require that all types that implement `Length` must also (separately) implement `PartialEq` via `trait Length: PartialEq {...}`.

Comment: Alternatively, the better method in general is just to make your own `equal_lengths` method in the `Length` trait, and give that `method` your default implementation of `self._standardized() == other._standardized()`, which doesn't overlap with the builtin `PartialEq` trait, since types might want equality apart from just length equality.

Comment: @Aplet123 can't you implement PartialEq for T: Lenght?

Comment: @Aplet123 Thanks. 1) Specialization -- and its current absence -- explains the `conflicting implementations ...` error. 2) "... since types might want equality apart from just length equality," combined with Rust's deliberate lack of overloading, is a solid argument for this being a bad idea, and implementing `equal_lengths()` seems like a good solution. 3) I think that the gap in my paradigm seems to be that Rust takes the Go approach of trying to discourage overloading in favor of explicitness.